# Verwendung von Präpositionen

Tags: preposition

Ausgehend von dieser Diskussion [Going to the train station: which prepositions can be used?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58172/going-to-the-train-station-which-prepositions-can-be-used/58173#58173), wüsste ich gerne, in welchen Zusammenhängen "ich gehe an den Bahnhof" verwendet wird. Ich würde mich sehr über fundierte Antworten freuen!

Comment: Wir treffen uns am Bahnhof und am Bahnhof steht ein Baum. Ich gehe zum Bäcker am Bahnhof. Ich gehe an den Bahnhof. Ich bringe meinen Koffer schon mal an den Bahnhof. Grammatisch ist die Lage glasklar. Voting to close as "opinon based".

Comment: Was ich spontan bei der Formulierung *ich gehe an den Bahnhof* assoziiere ist, dass die Toiletten im Inneren des Gebäudes nicht erreichbar sind...

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Ja, ein solcher Kontext wäre noch vorstellbar, aber würdest du sagen, dass "ich gehe zum Bahnhof" und "ich gehe an den Bahnhof" zwei beliebige Varianten sind (wie in dem gelinkten Post)?

Comment: @a_donda Nein, es geht nicht um "eine mögliche Präposition für "jemanden vor dem Bahnhof treffen". Lies bitte nochmal die Frage!

Comment: @Nico Nein, sie sind nicht austauschbar oder beliebig. *An* den Bahnhof gehen würde geradezu *betonen*, dass man nicht hinein geht.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Danke! So sehe ich das auch. Aber nochmal: Wie gängig sind für dich "ich gehe an den Bahnhof" und "ich bringe meine Koffer an den Bahnhof"?

Comment: @Nico Sie wären zumindest ungewöhnlich. So ungewöhnlich, dass es einen stutzen lässt. Ich kann allerdings nicht ausschließen, dass es hierzu regional oder millieubedingt andere Ansichten gibt.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Das tröstet mich!

Comment: @a_donda Du musst dich leider damit abfinden, dass deine Verwendung möglicherweise "milieubedingt" ist, wie es Volker anmerkt!

Comment: "ich gehe an den Bahnhof" würde ich regional grob im Raum Oberhausen-Wuppertal-Köln-Düsseldorf einordnen z.B. ".. isch jon aan d'r Bahnhof ... un hol mr e Zeidung"

Answer (score 2):

Im Satz "Ich gehe an den Bahnhof." liegt m.E. eine Verkürzung vor, z.B.:

> Ich gehe an den Bahnhof heran.

Ein möglicher Kontext dazu: Es gibt an der Außenmauer des Bahnhofs einen Briefkasten und zu diesem gehe ich hin.

Möglicher Dialog:

- Ich: "Ich bring noch den Brief weg."
- Gegenüber: "Welcher Briefkasten? Markthalle oder Bahnhof?"
- Ich: "Ich gehe an den Bahnhof."

D.h., der Bahnhof ist nicht das eigentliche Ziel, sondern etwas, dass in unmittelbarer Nähe des Bahnhofs ist. Geläufigere Formulierungen:

- "Ich gehe an den Strand." vs. "Ich gehe zum Strand."

  - Ist ambivalent, weil "Strand" in beiden Fällen das Ziel sein kann.
  - Das Ziel bei "an" ist stattdessen "zwischen den Zeilen" etwas gemeint, das auf/bei dem Strand ist, während bei "zum" der Strand das Ziel ist,
- "Ich schwimme ans Ufer." vs. "Ich schwimme zum Ufer."

  - Beides gebräuchlich, um deutlich zu machen, dass der Rand des Gewässers aufgesucht wird.
  - Bei "an" ist im unausgesprochenen Subtext z.B. mitgemeint, welches Ufer: ein See kann mehrere haben.

Wäre der Bahnhof das eigentliche Ziel, wäre "Ich gehe zum Bahnhof." sowohl m.E. üblicher als auch grammatisch korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Fassen wir zusammen:

Der Satz

> *Ich gehe an den Bahnhof.

ist nach den Regeln und Üblichkeiten der gepflegten deutschen Sprache sowie des Schulunterrichts kein wohlgeformter Satz. Man würde die Sache einfach anders ausdrücken, zum Beispiel

> Ich gehe zum Bahnhof.
>
> Ich gehe auf den Bahnhof. [Dies schon etwas altertümlich]

Trotzdem ist der Satz *Ich gehe an den Bahnhof* problemlos verständlich, und er kann deswegen in einer (aus verschiedenen Gründen ja oft mängelbehafteten) Alltagskommunikation auch durchflutschen, ohne dass er groß auffällt. Dies um so mehr als zunehmend auch Leute die deutsche Sprache im Alltag benutzen, die mit anderer Erstsprache aufgewachsen sind und darum nicht jede Nuance richtig (hier im Sinne von: traditionsgemäß) "erfühlen".

Man kann daneben noch für sonderliche Ausdrücke auch extrem besondere Situationen erfinden, die die besondere Ausdrucksweise rechtfertigen können. Das ist dann meistens eher eine intellektuelle Übung und hat wenig Alltagsrelevanz. Im vorliegenden Fall von *Ich gehe an den Bahnhof* fällt es der versammelten Lesergemeinde hier aber, wie wir gesehen haben, schwer, eine solche Sondersituation zu beschreiben.

Comment: Was ist denn der Unterschied zwischen "Ich gehe an den Bahnhof" und "Ich gehe an den Strand" bzw "Ich gehe an die Bar". Oder sind die vielleicht gebräuchlich, aber eigentlich auch _nicht wohlgeformt_? Bin gerade am Hadern.

Comment: Natürlich geht niemand an den Bahnhof um den Zug zu nehmen. Aber beispielsweise um dort jemanden zu treffen (oder ein Geschäft zu machen wie ein humorvoller Kollege anmerkte :-)), eben schon. Das war das Thema meiner Antwort, um möglichst viele Fälle abzudecken. Alles andere, wie eine allgemeine sprachliche Verwendung von "an den" wurde von Dritten dazu konstruiert. Over and out, Affidavit Donda