# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Ich komme aus dem Theater." und "Ich komme vom Theater."?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, grammar-identification

Ich lerne gerade die Lokalepräpositionen und ich finde sie wirklich verwirrend. Meine Frage ist, ob es einen Unterschied gibt zwischen "Ich komme aus dem Theater." und "Ich komme vom Theater.". Eine Erklärung auf Englisch wäre gut.

Comment: Siehe auch diese verwandten Fragen: [Frage 1](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58172)  und [Frage 2](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58172).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es gibt vor allem dann einen Unterschied, wenn man vom physischen Theater, also dem Gebäude, spricht. In diesem Fall meint

> Ich komme aus dem Theater.

dass man aus dem Theatergebäude herauskommt und zum Beispiel auf die Straße vor dem Gebäude tritt. Hingegen meint

> Ich komme vom Theater.

nur, dass der Ausgangspunkt das Theater war. Es bezieht sich nicht direkt auf das Verlassen des Gebäudes.

Wenn das Theater als Organisation oder Institution gemeint ist, gibt es fast keinen Unterschied. In diesem Fall ist "Ich komme vom Theater" gebräuchlicher, aber "Ich komme aus dem Theater" (als Fach oder Beruf) ist auch möglich.

---

There's especially a difference if you're talking about the physical theatre, the theatre building. In this case,

> Ich komme aus dem Theater.

refers specifically to leaving the building and, for example, stepping onto the street in front of the building. On the other hand,

> Ich komme vom Theater.

only expresses that the starting point of your way was the theatre. It doesn't refer directly to leaving the theatre building.

If you're referring to the theatre as an organisation or institution, there's little to no difference between your examples. In this case, "Ich komme vom Theater" would be more common, but "Ich komme aus dem Theater" (as an art form or a profession) would be correct as well.

Answer (score 5):

To say "aus dem Theater" says that you were physically in the building, "vom Theater" could mean you were just nearby (in front of, perhaps). The later could also be used in a figurative sense, as "I used to work in/be related to acting, that's my background".

Comment: Please note: If the question is in German then this community wants the answer to be in that language as well. Only if the question is already in English then an English answer is assumed to be ok.

Comment: @TorstenLink According to the last sentence of the question, the OP prefers an explanation in English.

Comment: sorry, didn't read that last sentence...